# Creating Subdirectories with a for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, directory

```
 $product_Category = ' Electronics| Computers & Accessories| Monitors ';   

<!-- a simple div with some links --> 
    <div class="breadcrumb-killer flat">
        <a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a>
        <?php 
        $cats = explode("|",  $product_Category);
        for($k = 0; $k < count($cats); $k++) {
            for ($l=0; $l <= $k; $l++) { 
                $folder = permalink($cats[$l])."/" ;
                echo $folder;
            }

            echo '<a href="'.$folder.'">'.$cats[$k].'</a>';
        } 
        ?>
    </div>
```

I have categories separated with a delimeter as - Electronics| Computers & Accessories| Monitors

Am creating clean urls with this function

```
function permalink($var)
{
    $var = preg_replace('#([\W_]+)#', ' ', $var);
    $var = str_replace(' ', '-', $var);
    $var = strtolower($var);
    $var = rtrim($var, '-');
    $var = ltrim($var, '-'); 
    $var = trim($var);
    return $var;
}
```

when i output folder am getting this :

```
electronics/  electronics/computers-accessories/ electronics/computers-accessories/monitors/
```

Though the urs aren't constructed the way i want .
Am expecting urls to be like :

```
<a href="electronics/">Electronics</a>
<a href="electronics/computers-accessories/">Computers & Accessories</a>
<a href="electronics/computers-accessories/monitors/">Monitors</a>
```

this is what i am getting :

```
    <a href="electronics/">Electronics</a>
    <a href="computers-accessories/"> Computers &amp; Accessories</a>
    <a href="monitors/"> Monitors</a>
```

Comment: fyi, `$var = rtrim($var, '-'); $var = ltrim($var, '-');` is `$var = trim($var, '-');`

Comment: @mickmackusa is there any difference ?

Comment: Just clean your Variable before assign it inside your loop $folder = '' ;

Comment: I think this is the condensed form of `permalink()` : `return trim(preg_replace('~[^a-z\d]+~', '-', strtolower($var)), '-');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised my mistake - the inner for loop is to add the various parts together, but it's not adding them just replacing them, you need to reset it and add each segment on using `.=`...

```
    $folder = "";
    for ($l=0; $l <= $k; $l++) { 
        $folder .= permalink($cats[$l])."/" ;
        // echo $folder;
    }
```